# What size light bulb do I need?

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan

I’m assuming it’s an older model Hampton Bay ceiling fan but I bought an e12 bulb and it doesn’t fit, so now I need a converter!
Please help I’m going crazy trying to find out the size.

[image]

[image]

And, here's a video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHP5o.jpg

Comment: How about an E10 candelabra? That,s a much more common size than E12. Did you take this thing overseas?

Comment: post a photo instead of a video ... hold a ruler next to the socket

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I've added some images from you video, but @jsotola's suggestion of one with a ruler would help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: saying that the bulb does not fit is kind of useless ... saying that the bulb is too large or too small would be helpful

Comment: @jsotola the e12 light bulb fits in the socket perfectly but when I twist it, it doesn't connect. I posted on reddit and someone said it's most likely an e11 mini-can so I bought a converter on Amazon and will update when it comes in tomorrow